# What is the proper Rollup.js config for React-Native?

Tags: react-native, npm, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a component library for React-Native.

The bundling part using Rollup is a bit tricky for me.

When I try to bundle using the command `rollup -c` I get this error :

[image]

Here's my rollup.config.js :

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

Here's a piece of my tsconfig.json related to rollup it seems :

```
"jsx": "react-native",
"module": "ESNext",
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": "types",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "dist",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"emitDeclarationOnly": true
```

I really feel awkward with rollup.js, I'm grabbing some information here and there so a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Kind of. I found this library https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob which provide a full solution for building RN packages.